# Ampersands in hyperlinks cause W3C validation to fail

Tags: html, validation, web-standards, w3c-validation

I have a reacurring problem. I code nice standards compliant code only to have it fail due to ampersands within some of the hyperlink urls.

Does anyone know of a work around or hack for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [URL Encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the hyperlinks, so all characters are turned into a valid ASCII format and don't contain any (X)HTML entities.

For C# use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx), for PHP [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), for JavaScript `encodeURI`, etc... Finding the right method for the language you're using shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is actually better than `urlencode` for this.

Comment: ...I'd go as far as to call it *necessary*. `urlencode()` is the wrong approach. An ampersand has a special meaning in URLs (GET parameter separator) and `urlencode()` would *remove* that meaning by escaping them. We don't want to encode the ampersands in a URL context. We want to encode the ampersands in an HTML context. `htmlspecialchars()` does that.

Answer (score 13):

> I code nice standards compliant code only to have it fail due to ampersands within some of the hyperlink urls.

Unescaped ampersands in URLs (or anywhere else, if they're not part of an HTML entity!) **aren't** "nice standards compliant code".

Turn them into `&amp;` and you can accurately claim to have done this.

Comment: Grammar Nazi: /replace aren't with isn't

Comment: +1 Also good to know: An unmasked `&` will count as invalid *even in JavaScript blocks*, unless they are wrapped in `CDATA` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. URL encoding is a new one on me, I'm looking into it. There's a good link to the W3C URL encoding page provided by Ronald above.

Answer (score 5):

Did you make them & in the links like this?

```
&amp;
```

Answer (score -1):

CDATA works wonders where you have & in javascript strings..